# Random path generation algorithm with defined path size

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix, random

I'm trying to generate a path inside a matrix with a defined count of elements inside the picked path.

I can create from point A to point B with no problems using:

```
step(int[] s, int[] e) //start - end
{
   int d = delta(s, e);
   if (d > 1)
   {
      //spread around
      List<int[]> pts = new List<int[]>();
      pts.Add(new int[2] { s[0] -1, s[1]    }); //left
      pts.Add(new int[2] { s[0] +1, s[1]    }); //right
      pts.Add(new int[2] { s[0]   , s[1] +1 }); //top
      pts.Add(new int[2] { s[0]   , s[1] -1 }); //bot

      //remove out of bounds points
      List<int[]> goodPoints = new List<int[]>();
      foreach (var p in pts)
      {
         if (checkValidBoundries(p))
         {
            goodPoints.Add(p);
         }
      }

      //calculate lowest deltas
      int lowestDelta = int.MaxValue;
      int[] bestFit = new int[2];
      foreach (var p in goodPoints)
      {
         int localDelta = delta(p, e);
         if (localDelta == lowestDelta) //local shuffle
         {
            if (await coinFlip())
            {
               bestFit = p;
            }
         }
         else if (localDelta < lowestDelta)
         {
            lowestDelta = localDelta;
            bestFit = p;
         }
      }

      matrix.setValue(bestFit[0], bestFit[1]);
      step(bestFit, e);
   }
}
```

This code will recursive iterates until the path is over.
This is the way I get the shortest path.

So my question is: How can I define a number of elements in the path?

For example: from A to B this algorithm gives me 6 elements, no matter the path it will always use the lowest delta between points. But if I want this path to be 7, 8 elements long?

I tried to pick one element at a time from the path and lock it so next run it will not consider it as valid, but it keeps going wrong.

The new path can be random no problem I just want to control the number of elements inside the "best path".

Any help? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Instead of making this recursive, return the processed data from a single step. Then run the function required amount of times using a loop and you will get the result.

Comment: Hi, but how can I keep it going and have the same point A -> B? This is the part I'm in trouble. I have the shortest path but where in my running should I do a move like: while(pathsize not equal defined pathsize) so walk random around and connect to point B?

Comment: I don't think that you can achieve paths of arbitrary lengths in a matrix when you can only go up, down, left and right. The shortest distance _d\*_ is the Manhattan distance between the points. You can only make a path longer by turning a straight segment into a U by adding 2 perpendicular "stems", so your path can only have lengths of _d\*_ + 2 · _k_. (But you can use the strategy of making U-shaped dents to make your path longer if you take care not to fold the path onto itself.)

Comment: Why someone downvote my question?

Comment: Hi @MOehm, I got your point this seems valid to me. Can you give me some tips on that in an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to find the nearest path between two points A and B in a grid with no obstacles. Movement must be in one of the four cardinal directions. You then want to lengthen this path so that it has a certain length.

First, if there are no obstacles, you don't need to probe all directions. For example, if B is 4 steps to the east and two steps to the north of A, just pick steps from {E, E, E, E, N, N} randomly (or shuffle the array) until you arrive.

The shortest distance d* between A and B is the Manhattan diatance:

d* = |A.x - B.x| + |A.y - B.y|

If you imagine the grid coloured like a checkerboard, the distance between A and B is even if both have the same colour and odd otherwise. This does not only apply to the sorest distance, but to the distance of any valid path between A and B. Hence, you can only get distances of d* + 2·k.

You can make longer paths by adding small "detours" to your ideal path:

```
        · · · · · · · ·            · · · · · · · ·            · · · · · · · ·
        · · · · · · B ·            · · · · · · B ·            · · · · · · B ·
        · · · · ┌───┘ ·            · u · · ┌───┘ ·            · · · · ┌───┘ ·
        · · · · │ · · ·            · ╒═╕ · └─╖ · ·            · · · ╔═╡ · · ·
        · ┌─────┘ · · ·            · │ └─────╜ v ·            · ┌───╜ ╧ w · ·
        · A · · · · · ·            · A · · · · · ·            · A · · · · · ·
        · · · · · · · ·            · · · · · · · ·            · · · · · · · ·
```

Each of the "dents" u and v add two segments to your path. When you make dents, take care not to make a dent, where there is already a piece of the path: Dent w has a piece of the path folded back on itself, so that there is a dead end. You can remove the dead end, but the path will have the same length as before.

How to implement all this is left as an exercise to the reader. `:)`

Comment: You are super right! That's clarification I was looking for. Many thanks